# Router with WOL support

Tags: router

I have a Speedport 921V which does [NOT](https://telekomhilft.telekom.de/t5/Geraete-Zubehoer/Speedport-W921V/m-p/906479#M145825) support Wake on LAN (WOL) over the local network. I am looking for a Fritzbox or similar which has at least the same features as my Speedport 921V and supports WOL over the local network. I use WOL2 to wake up my computer.

PS: Please not, that the topic is not to wake up my computer via the internet.

Comment: What's your budget? Do you need an integrated switch/AP?

Comment: 250 €, yes, the Speedport has 4 LAN connectors.